How do we increase the number of questions being asked?
I noticed that our new question per day is really low. What can we do to overcome this?
Should we seed more content ourselves?
I can think of few newbies questions I can ask an answer myself. Is it good practice to do so on beta?

possible duplicate of What can we improve? The site seems to stagnate


What can we do to overcome this?

Promote the site! Get new users. Join or start site-promotion activities.

Should we seed more content ourselves?

Yes, of course! More content, means higher likelihood of RE turning up in search results.

Is it good practice to do so on beta?

Stack Exchange encourages self-answered questions. There is nothing wrong in doing so.

Could we introduce RE puzzles, like PCG or Project Euler? I'm a RE noob, so I could benefit from some "simple" RE tasks which have a clear solution. 
Maybe it's also fun for existing members to think of new puzzles instead of waiting for new questions.

This did come up a few months ago and was discussed. The idea did not gain much traction then. It would be great if you or other members would be willing to get together and organize something. In fact, its on this page itself.

One thing we could try is to actively watch the RE related question on SO (and maybe a few other sites) and ask to migrate them here. A few examples: 1, 2, 3, 4.

How do I migrate a question to here, when I flag a question as off-topic RE is not shown on options list ?

@Mellowcandle: according to this "Migration to other site is possible only by flagging question and reviewing by moderators" :(

Do not flag questions for migration unless they are off-topic (or at least borderline) where they are. Your examples aren't really off-topic, only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261850/finding-a-base-address-from-jvm-generated-code might be a candidate for migration (if SO doesn't want it, it does become fair game).

I could be wrong but in RE there is a real big gap between experienced and newbies, so what do you think about the following:

To encourage question asking there must be constant problem that people deal with, SO
We can create a section where experienced reversers (but do not have to) give problems to solve (but who ever asks must already know the answer) - like some sort of a challenge and it should be always a hard one. This could be voted by high rank users.
who ever wants to solve this challenge can get back to question section and ask questions to solve the challenge.

I think by this way we will "synthetically" rise the question number and enrich the audience. 

This was discussed in last week's community chat. Take a look at the transcripts. And yes, it is an excellent idea and will surely increase engagement. Why dont you start a separate meta post about this? This idea will take some time to get off the ground so the earlier we discuss it the better :)

People will ask more questions if they feel they get meaningful feedback on the question.

Set a goal of ensuring each question asked gets meaningful feedback within 1 week of posting.

This doesn't have to be an answer, it could simply be framing to identify what the topics, technologies or terms involved are.

more answers will probably attract more people to come to ask questions, ive asked a few and nobody answers nor votes up. Because everyones reputation is at zero even long time members cant vote anything up and everything gets buried in zeros

Exactly. It seems that there is a limited number of participants who can contribute on the specific topics. Thus, the response level is very low.
It looks similar to the youtube videos on the topic, which either very specific and not applicable to 99% of other cases or very basic...

get rid of downvoting very frustrating feature as it doesnt tell you why something is being downoted
